# Flux: Understanding state in ReduceStore

Tags: javascript, state, store, flux

I am trying to create a simple counter application to learn more about the Flux architecture, but it hasn't really clicked yet. Part of it is related to the implementation of `ReduceStore`.

In the Flux docs a simple example is given containing this reduce function:

```
reduce(state: number, action: Object): number {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return state + 1;

    case 'square':
      return state * state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The function is documented as follows:

> **reduce(state: T, action: Object): T** Reduces the current state, and an action to the new state of this store. All subclasses must implement this method. This method should be pure and have no side-effects.

In other words: The reduce function does not mutate state, but returns the result of on operation with it (in the example an addition or multiplication).

While I have understood the general concept, I wonder how to actually use such store. If I got that correctly, a store should hold a certain state (the Flux docs mention the playback time of a video as example). But the `ReduceStore` does not implement any state, it has to be passed as an argument to the reducer. That means the actual state needs to be stored elsewhere in my application – probably in the component rendering the counter (the state of a counter app) which seems wrong to me.

Is this assumption correct and this is fine in a Flux architecture or am I missing something regarding a `ReduceStore` – maybe a different use case or something?

Comment: Check out this very nice tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-redux/

Comment: In `Redux` there is a function `createStore` which creates a store with your reducers, redux store manages your state, and it is really a magic until you get some familiarity with redux architecture.